# I am getting error while drawing shear diagram on beams

Tags: python

I am getting error while drawing shear diagram on beams. From A support to B support my code works fine. But after B support the values ​​increase directly if need to increase after sharp decrease. How can I include the load of support B?

h t t p s://w w w.hizliresim. com/2rbtx9b

```
from sympy import solve , symbols ,Eq
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
By = symbols("By")

def simple_beam_uniform(L1,L2,g):
    """


    """
    # Support reactions ...
    By = symbols("By")
    load_trans = (L1+L2)*g    # Transformation uniform load to distributed load
    location = (L1+L2)/2      # Location of distributed load
    Sr_rigth_eq = ((By*L1)-(load_trans * location)) # Eqn of support rigth
    Sr_rigth = solve(Sr_rigth_eq)
    Sr_left = load_trans - Sr_rigth[0]   # Eqn of support left
    print("Support leations of left side : ",Sr_left,"kN")
    print("Support leations of rigth side : ",Sr_rigth,"kN")

    
    # Shear Fucntion
    V_function = lambda x : -Sr_left + g * x
    v_values = list(map(V_function , np.arange(L1+1)))
    print(v_values)

    # Moment Function
    M_function = lambda x : -Sr_left *x + (g*x*(x)/2)
    m_values = list(map(M_function , np.arange(L1+1)))
    print(m_values)

    # Plotting
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(np.arange(L1+1) , v_values , label = "shear")
    plt.plot(np.arange(L1+1) , m_values , label = "moment")
    plt.xlim(0 , 15)



simple_beam_uniform(15,7.5,9.5)
```

Comment: You should supply the error. Also, this is quite a bit of code, you should consider making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So this is a uniformly loaded beam, with pin support on one side and roller on the other? In that case you would have a reaction point load at each endpoint that is half the total force to resist the total applied uniform load.